# Spring - Enable/disable @Transactional depending on the profile being used

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, transactions

My application currently uses cucumber scenarios as the test cases. There are cucumber step classes that turns the test cases into junit tests.

I have two configurations for the same test case - one is in-memory, the other is integrated (talk to database).

I have two spring profiles: "inMemory" & "integratedTest", and two junit runners have the two different profiles to kick off two tests.

For my integrated test, I annotated the cucumber step class with `@Transactional` to help me handle the database transaction. But for the in-memory the annotation it does not work with `@Transactional`. And the error I get is:

```
Transaction manager [ResourcelessTransactionManager] does not support transaction suspension.
```

I use `HibernateTransactionManager` as the transaction manager for the integrated profile.

I wonder if I can in some way disable `@Transactional` when I am using inMemory profile and enable it when I use integratedTest profile.

Any other high level solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After trying some options, my final way to go was to implement the `doSuspend()` on `ResourcelessTransactionManager` (having my own implementation of the class). Since the `suspend()` method on `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` will call `doSuspend()` which in default will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring global transaction manager with Transaction attribute as Supports, this will only participate in transaction only if already present.

Refer: http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2012/10/attributes-in-springs-declarative.html

@Transactional(value = "tmanager", propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)

Comment: The problem is that with inMemory profile, ResourcelessTransactionManager is also a PlatformTransactionManager, so @Transactional will still check for the support for suspension.

Comment: IMO when propagation attribute is Supports then it will not check for suspension. It will not create a transaction it self if not already present. You only have to get the Bean out of Transaction context.

Comment: got it! Thanks for your suggestion. But my legacy code requires the transaction manager to be present. So I went ahead and implemented a new ResourcelessTransactionManager.